# How to Pass Windows key + L combination in remote desktop (MSTSC or RDP)?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

how do i lock remote desktop screen (RDP or MSTSC) ?. Is there any shortcut key for lock screen in remote desktop. For example in local desktop if we press Windows key + L key combination it locks the local client computer, is there any equivalent version of key combination in RDP ?

Comment: Possible answers can be found [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735788/locking-computer-remotely)

Comment: What is the practical difference between locking and disconnecting?

Comment: @NiallJones we have ctrl + alt + end(Remote Desktop) for windows security which is equivalent to ctrl + alt + del in Local client. Is there any shortcut key instead of run32.exe user32.dll and LockWorkstation combination? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Sumeet - [Are you connecting to the remote desktop in window or full screen mode?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-shortcut-keys).  If it's full screen mode just select the appropriate option and the standard shortcut will work.

Answer (score 16):

Cntrl + Alt + End will bring up the same screen that Cntrl+Alt+Del does on the home machine.  Just select lock and your remote session is locked.

Answer (score 6):

you could create a shortcut somewhere on the remote machine (i.e. on the desktop) that points to "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation" and in the option fill the "Shortcut Key" with something like CTRL-ALT-L, it will lock the session

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wrote an keyboard filter driver which will send the keys depending on the session handle. One key thing i noticed was when the virtual or on-screen keyboard is toggled on, and if you pass Win + any key(Virtual key) + L it only locks RDP or remote session. So i have written a keyboard filter driver which will send in the scan code along with the Win and L key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psexec` with `-s` (run as system) and `-i` (interact with user session)

```ps
psexec -s -i \\[hostname] cmd /c "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation"
```

It works, but it would also show cmd for a split second on User's system.